# How to convert Java Timestamp to mySQL datetime function

Tags: java, mysql, sql, datetime, timestamp

My code uses `Java.sql.Timestamp` to store an update date. I want to take that date and store it into a mySQL datetime object. My problem is that the `Java.util.Timestamp` returns a date in the format of **2013-12-09 00:00:00.00** but the mySQL colunmn wants the format in **2013-12-09 00:00:00**. So it looks like I need to trim off the .00 of the `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to insert timestamp in mysql as String, just treat it as `java.sql.Timestamp` and use `PreparedStatement` to set the value properly

Comment: I do just add the timestamp and it kicks this error `com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'update_date' at row 1`